# Does build.xml sign APKs in debug mode?

Tags: android

I've been looking through the build.xml file in the sdk/tools/ant directory of the Android SDK. I can see that the release build accesses a custom key for signing the APK, but I don't see where the debug build accesses a debug key.

It's strange, because the default target is <debug> and its description states that the application is signed with the debug key. But from what I've seen, none of the targets required by <debug> sign the application.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does get signed. Look in your user's home directory, for a directory called .android. There should be a debug.keystore in there.

Comment: Thank you, but my question involves the targets in build.xml. I can't find any targets that sign the APK if it was compiled in debug mode. There are, however, targets that sign the APK if it was compiled in release mode.